# Получение значений из формы php

Tags: php, html

при отправке сообщений с формы не отправляются значения, как правильно их получить?

PHP:

```
<?php
$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$mess = $_POST['mess'];

   $to      = 'asdrw@gmail.com';
   $headers = 'From: example@gmail.com' . "\r\n";
   $subject = "Письмо с блога!";
   $message = "Имя:" .$name. "\nEmail:" .$email. "\n\n\t" .$mess;
   mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
?>
```

HTML:

```
<form action="php/success.php">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="inputEmail">Адрес email:</label>
    <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email" id="inputEmail" placeholder="Введите email" required>
  </div >
  <div class="form-group">
  <label for="inputName">Имя:</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" id="inputName" placeholder="Введите имя:" required>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="inputMess">Ваше сообщениe:</label>
    <textarea class="form-control" name="mess" placeholder="Ваше сообщение" required></textarea>
  </div>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Отправить</button>
</form>
```

Comment: `<form action="php/success.php">` => `<form action="php/success.php" method="post">`

Comment: @Let'ssayPie благодарю, как всегда мелочь пропустил и искал проблему в php